# How to await Redux state update in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following action creator that I need to await in a React component. It needs to run to completion (after the reducer updated the store) as React component needs access to it. How can I use the following in my React component? Is this what the experimental Suspense API would provide?

```
await updateLocation()
```

````
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (res) => {
                if (res) {
                    reverseGeoCodeCoords(res)
                        .then((d) => {
                                   dispatch({
                                            type: UPDATE_USER_LOCATION,
                                            payload,
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                }
            },
            (err) => {

            }
        );
    } else {
        console.log("Browser doesn't support geolocation.");
    }
};```
````

Comment: you could use suspense but why not just listen for a success failure from the redux action?

Comment: How do I listen for that?